# Background position image overlay (Works in IE, not in Mozilla/Chrome/Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, css, google-chrome

I am having an issue positioning a background image using the following jquery background position command in Firefox, Google Chrome, and Safari.  The code works correctly in IE 8.

$('#element').css({ backgroundPosition: 'xpx ypx' });

The desired effect is a continuous stream of fluid from the right side of the screen to the left, blurred out while behind the main page content.  This is achieved using 2 fluid images, one completely sharp and one completely blurred.  As the user resizes the window, a jquery function calculates the appropriate positioning of the blurred image (set as a background image) and edits the backgroundposition css attribute.

The x position of the image is calculated dynamically based on window size and the y position is static.  The css appears to be modified correctly (note the backgroundposition display in the right most text box).  However, the background image I am attempting to overlay is absent in mozilla/chrome/safari. See jscript code below:

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
    // image positioning variables 
     var windowwidth = $(window).width();
     var imgwidth = $('#imgFluid').width();
     var offset = $('#divFluidBlur').offset();

     // calculate and implement position
     blurPositionLeft = (windowwidth - imgwidth) - offset.left;
     $('#divFluidBlur').css({ backgroundPosition: blurPositionLeft + 'px' + ' 30px' });

    // debug: display actual css Background Position of element to text box
     $("#txtActualBackgroundpos").val(document.getElementById ("divFluidBlur").style.backgroundPosition); }
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing should work. Anyway, you may want to try a little cleaner version: $('#divFluidBlur').css('background-position', blurPositionLeft + 'px' + ' 30px'); And you may want to use Firebug to temporary disable or change values of other styles that could be iterfering.

Could you privide an online example of the problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a place to host a live example.  I added some details, hopefully that will help to explain the issue better.
-Andrew

Comment: Did you do an alert() of the value of X to see if it's correct?

Comment: Yes I actually used a text box to ensure that the css property is being updated.  It is being correctly updated in all browsers.  It displays correctly in IE, but not in firefox, chrome, or safari.